# Prevent object from leaving camera bounds

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm playing a little with the phaser framework and try to make a simple *"fall down"* game. The goal is to fall fast enough without getting pushed out at the top of the screen:

To accomplish this I set the canvas size to *800x600*:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, ...);
```

and resizing the world in `create()` to *800x6000*:

```
game.world.resize(800, 6000);
```

In `update()` I move the camera `1` down:

```
game.camera.y += 1;
```

and check if the ball is still inside the camera:

```
if (!ball.inCamera) {
   // ...         
}
```

My Question is:
On the left and on the right the world borders are limiting the moveability of the ball (because of that the ball can't leave the camera there). How can I prevent the ball from "falling" out the camera on the bottom, but still be able to get pushed out the camera at the top?

Is there something similar to

```
game.physics.arcade.checkCollision.down = true;
```

but for the camera bounds?

**Edit**

This is how the ball is created:

```
ball = game.add.sprite(game.world.width / 2, 20, "ball");
game.physics.arcade.enable(ball);
ball.body.gravity.y = 1000;
```

To move the ball I check for key presses and then change the `ball.body.velocity` parameters.

Comment: How do you move the ball? Does it have physics?

Comment: Well, because physics has nothing to do with the camera (and indeed it shouldn't), an elegant solution would be to create an invisible body, align its top with the bottom camera bound and move it with camera, thus still allowing the ball to be moved out of the view at the top, but not allowing it to fall down.

Comment: Thank you sir for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @KamenMinkov you should add an answer

Comment: ... if only the asker would return again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physics has nothing to do with the camera (and indeed it shouldn't), an elegant solution would be to create an invisible body, align its top with the bottom camera bound and move it with camera, thus still allowing the ball to be moved out of the view at the top, but not allowing it to fall down.